# How can I prevent Quill from converting script elements to paragraphs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

I need to allow a user to paste script tags into a raw HTML editor using React Quill. I have the raw HTML editor working but any script elements get converted to paragraph elements (I'm assuming this is to prevent XSS and I tried to argue against allowing script tags). Is there any way to override this behavior? I'm very new to Quill and haven't worked on text editors before so the documentation is a bit overwhelming.

Comment: Are you expecting the script to be displayed as text, or executed?

Comment: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2048

Comment: @DBS that's actually a good point. I'll check on the requirements but let's assume I'm expecting it to be executed. In either case I can't have the library converting script tags to p tags

Comment: @isherwood yes I know it's a security issue. However it shouldn't be the library making that security decision for the developer. TinyMCE allows scripts, though we can't use it.

Comment: The point is that it's not an available feature (that I'm aware of). Doesn't help to philosophize at _me_. :)

Comment: @isherwood fair, just hoping to find some way around it. Back to the drawing board then

Comment: One abstract idea would be to preprocess the input to mask or escape the script element, then post-process it to reintroduce it. I'm not that familiar with Quill, though.